# Which criterions to decide which Feature Selection method WAS best adapted to my data

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, predictive-models, feature-selection, model-evaluation

For **one dataset** and **one response variable**, i have run several repetitions (around a 100) of **different feature selection methods**. (Elastic Net, VSURF + RF, BestSubset ...)

**For each method, the repetitions were done by repeating the 10-fold process around 10 times on the training dataset.** Each feature selection methods are run on the same train fold and test fold as the other methods, which means that we can compare the performance of the various methods accross repetitions.

**My goal is to decide which method performed best on average on predicting new data.**

I want a method which is both *stable* (low SD of RMSEP) and has a **low predictive RMSE** (RMSEP).
Therefore, i was thinking of using as a criterion to select the FS method as follow:

> mean(RMSEP) + sd(RMSEP)

**Therefore, my question is:**
***Is that a good criterion to decide which FS method was the best for my initial dataset ?***

Now, i think we could also add weighing to both Means and SD of the RMSEP based on personal preferences (Stability over lucky low RMSEP), but i don't have the experience to assess the best choice.   *ex: criterion = Mean(RMSEP) + 2 x sd(RMSEP)*

We won't discuss here why i want to perform the feature selection as it is not a problem.